# How to bold specific text of tree item?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I want to display specific text of tree item in bold. How can I do this ?

We are using JFace treeviewer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this JFace Snippet: [Snippet049StyledCellLabelProvider](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFaceSnippets#Snippet049StyledCellLabelProvider)...